# Setting ASIO timeout for stream

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am trying to a set a timeout for a socket that I have created using ASIO in boost with no luck. I have found the following code elsewhere on the site:

```
tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec  = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    setsockopt(socket.native(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, sizeof(tv));
    setsockopt(socket.native(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, &tv, sizeof(tv));
boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);
```

The timeout remains at the same 60 seconds as opposed to the 5 seconds I am looking for in the connect call. What am I missing? Note the connect code works fine in all other cases (where there is no timeout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket options you've set don't apply to `connect` AFAIK.
This can be accomplished by using the asynchronous asio API as in the following asio [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/async_tcp_client.cpp).

The interesting parts are setting the timeout handler:

```
deadline_.async_wait(boost::bind(&client::check_deadline, this));
```

Starting the timer

```
void start_connect(tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iter)
{
  if (endpoint_iter != tcp::resolver::iterator())
  {
    std::cout << "Trying " << endpoint_iter->endpoint() << "...\n";

    // Set a deadline for the connect operation.
    deadline_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(60));

    // Start the asynchronous connect operation.
    socket_.async_connect(endpoint_iter->endpoint(),
        boost::bind(&client::handle_connect,
        this, _1, endpoint_iter));
  }
  else
  {
    // There are no more endpoints to try. Shut down the client.
    stop();
  }
}
```

And closing the socket which should result in the connect completion handler to run.

```
void check_deadline()
{
  if (stopped_)
    return;

  // Check whether the deadline has passed. We compare the deadline against
  // the current time since a new asynchronous operation may have moved the
  // deadline before this actor had a chance to run.
  if (deadline_.expires_at() <= deadline_timer::traits_type::now())
  {
    // The deadline has passed. The socket is closed so that any outstanding
    // asynchronous operations are cancelled.
    socket_.close();

    // There is no longer an active deadline. The expiry is set to positive
    // infinity so that the actor takes no action until a new deadline is set.
    deadline_.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);
  }

  // Put the actor back to sleep.
  deadline_.async_wait(boost::bind(&client::check_deadline, this));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just figured out that they don't apply to connect. I was going to cobble a timer to perform my own SIG processing. I like your way better.

Comment: Ok great :) It's not my way, it's from the example by asio's author, Chris Kohlhoff.

Comment: This is a great solution Ralf, I commonly do the same thing where I use an existing asio::io_service for timers to handle my timeouts. The only extra I would add to this is that you can bind a callback to execute on timeout. If your system wants/needs a notification that a timeout has occurred to perform some cleanup, retry or other such things without stopping the socket, then you can put the code for that in a timer expiry callback.